# SVG Path representing line not showing with working and non working examples

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on using path data to show a line and it used to work but in this case it's not. I've added a working example below.

**Non working example:**

```css
#Path_2 {
 opacity: 1;
 overflow: visible;
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: rgb(233, 233, 240);
 stroke-width: 2px;
 stroke-linejoin: miter;
 stroke-linecap: butt;
 stroke-miterlimit: 4;
}
.Path_2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 27.80859375px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 2px;
 transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div style="outline: 0px dashed red;">
<svg viewBox="-835.0799560546875 2509.80859375 400 0" class="Path_2">
 <path id="Path_2" d="M -835.0799560546875 2509.80859375 C -835.0799560546875 2509.80859375 -435.0799560546875 2509.80859375 -435.0799560546875 2509.80859375">
 </path>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Working example:**

```css
#Line_84 {
 opacity: 1;
 overflow: visible;
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
 stroke-width: 1px;
 stroke-linejoin: miter;
 stroke-linecap: butt;
 stroke-miterlimit: 4;
}
.Line_84 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 18.5px;
 left: 17.419921875px;
 width: 99.1396484375px;
 height: 14.990234375px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Line_84">
 <path id="Line_84" d="M 0 0 L 99 14">
 </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: All the co-ordinate values are the same so there's no line.

Comment: The height of your SVG canvas is 0: viewBox="-835.0799560546875 2509.80859375 400 **0**" Try changing it to ` viewBox="-830.0799560546875 2500.80859375 400 20"` Remove `.Path_2{height: 2px;}` Also the `overflow:visible` should be on the SVG element

Comment: Increasing the viewbox height to 1 or more it is showing it now.